# How do I detect end of scrolling on a container in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to detect then the container has been scrolled all the way to the bottom and I have the code that works well on many devices yet it fails to recognize when the element is scrolled to the bottom on some. I suppose that the error happens because different screen sizes but I still have no idea how to fix the calculation so it covers every case.

Here's the code:

```
  const handleScroll = (e: React.UIEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    const { scrollHeight, scrollTop, clientHeight } = e.currentTarget
    const bottom = Math.abs(scrollHeight - clientHeight - scrollTop) < 10
    if (bottom) {
      setPage((prev) => prev + 1)
    }
  }
```

No matter what I tried, I cannot reproduce the bug on my laptops but QA found this but on her device and my coworker also has this error on his Windows computer. I also tried to implement a hook with Intersection Observer but it fails to load the container ref since the component is conditionally rendered.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried it with a vanilla `addEventListener` and a `ref`

Comment: May not be the answer you are looking for, but Instead of checking the difference <10 (a rather arbitrary number), check if scrollTop + clientHeight >= scrollHeight.

Comment: @DeeGee tried that but got the same outcome